# Select the ID that have all its values greater than a specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select the `IDs` that have all the values greater than a number, example greater than 4.

If I have the ID 1 (with 3 rows), values: 3, 6, 8; and the ID 2, with values: 7, 5; I want to return the ID 2. (all its values that are GREATER THAN 4).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This should give the desired results.

```
Select id from table group by id having min(value) > 4;
```

Comment: Yey! Thx. Works! :)